# URL rewrite configuration on Azure

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, gateway

I have WAF, Application Gateway and a VM in place in Azure cloud. I have deployed an application in VM, which is running on tomcate and on port 8280.

I have domain name www.abc.com. In DNS entry, www.abc.com is pointing to my Azure App Gateway on port 80. 
I am able to access the my application using IP and port. for example:- 
http://X.X.X.X:8280/MyApps/page1 and http://X.X.X.X:8280/MyApps/page2.

I am trying to configure App Gateway, so that when I try to open using domain name. My requirement is when I hit www.abc.com, it should redirect to URL www.abc.com/page1. I tried to setup the listener with basic type and also path based. But no success. When I try to hit www.abc.com, it throws error:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

The 502 error always shows that there is a firewall restiction from your application gateway instance to your backend VM. You can verify if there are blocking the traffics in the NSG associated with your application gateway subnet or VM subnet. Also, this might be caused by inproperly configuring the custom health probe. You also can get more reasons from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502).

Moreover, you can confirm you have set the [url-based path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal) correctly. Pay attention to the path and port.